How to evaluate this integral? $\int_0^a x^4(a-x)^2/(a+x)^2 dx $
The real question was -
Find the volume of the solid formed by the revolution of the following curve about the X axis.
$y(a+x) = x^2(a-x)$
Volume integral will be -
V= $\int_0^a y^2dx $
V = $\int_0^a x^4(a-x)^2/(a+x)^2 dx $
I tried to integrate this by -

Long division method. Divide the numerator by the denominator and then obtain the expression. However, I obtained the incorrect answer everytime.

Use trigonometric substitution.


$ x = acos2\theta $
$ dx = -2asin2\theta d\theta $
But, the integrand became very complex. No idea, how to proceed further.
The correct answer is $2\pi a^3(log2-2/3)$ .
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
Edit - As many people said this in the comments, yes I believe there is a typo in the question. It was printed wrong in all of the sources of the book.
For $y^2(a+x) = x^2(a-x)$, the integral will evaluate to $2\pi a^3(log2-3)$.
For $y(a+x) = x^2(a-x)$, the integral will evaluate to $a^5(208/15 - ln2)$ (ive been getting this too + two people verified this in the answers. )
Thank you for catching this mistake. People at mathstackexchange truly are wonderful at maths. :)
Have a good day!

For the question in title, I do not see how $\pi$ could appear

Hint : Let $x=u-a$ and expand

If the question is correct, the answer is wrong. Any typo ?

You should have something dependent on $a^5$ if your formula is right

The "correct answer" is wrong.

Antiderivative is $\displaystyle x\rightarrow -20 {{a}^{5}} \log{\left( x+a\right) }-\frac{4 {{a}^{6}}}{x+a}+\frac{{{x}^{5}}}{5}-a {{x}^{4}}+\frac{8 {{a}^{2}} {{x}^{3}}}{3}-6 {{a}^{3}} {{x}^{2}}+16 {{a}^{4}} x$

@917 If the question is correct, then the answer given is incorrect. I am under the impression that there is a typo in the question, because if we consider $y^2(a+x) = x^2(a-x)$ instead of $y(a+x) = x^2(a-x)$, the answer you wrote fits. If so, please edit your question correcting the typo.

@Bml I think you are right. The thing is, this same question was written in everything I rechecked it from, my online pdf, my library's textbook. The answer does indeed match, when it's $y^2$. Thank you for the correction. Let me edit the question highlighting this change. Sorry for the error.

Rescale the integral first with $x\to ax$ and it suffices to integrate
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{x^4(1-x)^2}{(1+x)^2} dx=\int_0^1 x^4 -\frac{4x^5}{(1+x)^2}\ dx= \frac{11}5-20J_4
$$
where $J_n =\int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{1+x}\ dx$ can be reduced systemically via
$$J_n =\frac1{n}-J_{n-1},\>\>\> J_0=\ln2
$$
As a result,
$J_4= \frac14-\frac13+\frac12-1+J_0=-\frac7{12}+\ln2
$
and
$$I=\frac{11}5-20\left( -\frac7{12}+\ln2\right)=\frac{208}{15}-20\ln2
$$

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^a \frac{x^4(a-x)^2}{(a+x)^2} dx\\
&\overset{u=\frac{a-x}{a+x}}=2a^5\int_0^1 \frac{u^2(1-u)^4}{(1+u)^6}du\\
&\overset{z=\frac{1-u}{1+u}}=a^5\int_0^1\frac{z^4(1-z)^2}{(1+z)^2}dz\\
&=a^5\left[-20\ln(1+z)-\frac{4}{1+z}+\frac{z^5}{5}-z^4+\frac{8z^3}{3}-6z^2+16z\right]_0^1\\
&=\boxed{a^5\left(\frac{208}{15}-20\ln 2\right)}
\end{align}

Sure the first couple of lines are a very complicated way to achieve $z=ax$?

Probably. I like this change of variable. Sometimes it's magic!

Oh I agree about that, but to do it and at once undo it is maybe a wee bit too indulgent!
